# Display the paramiko log for Azure Function in python on Azure

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, azure-functions, paramiko

I'd like to know how to display the paramiko log (same log as would be written to a file when running paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")) when running the following Azure Function in python on Azure. When I run the code on my local computer I do get the paramiko log output, but not when the Azure Function is run on Azure.

```
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
import paramiko


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.Logger.root.level = 10
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
          
    # Used for getting access to secrets on Azure key vault for authentication purposes
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="InsertVaultURL", credential=credential)
    secret_name = secret_client.get_secret("InsertSecretUsernameName")
    secret_pass = secret_client.get_secret("InsertSecretPasswordName")
    secret_host_key = secret_client.get_secret("InsertSecretHostKeyName")
    
    # Server name for FSTP server 
    host_name = 'InsertFSTPHostAddress'
          
    # Connecting to FSTP server
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.get_host_keys().add(hostname = host_name, keytype='ssh-rsa', key = paramiko.PKey(data = secret_host_key.value.encode('ascii')))
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.connect(hostname = host_name, port = 22, username=secret_name.value, password=secret_pass.value)
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

    # Perform some activity with SFTP connection

    # Close the SFTP session
    sftp.close()

    # Close SSH Client
    ssh.close()
```

My host.json file has the following contents:

```
{
  "version":  "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

I have also included PYTHON_ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING = 1 in the configuration settings of my Azure Function on the Azure Portal to no avail.